# Snackbar descuadrada

Tags: android, google-maps

tengo una snackbar que se ejecuta al hacer click en un marcador, el problema que tengo es la posición donde se abre la snackbar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se interrumpe con los botones de accion de android y mi idea es moverla un poco mas arriba, a continuacion el codigo que estoy utilizando

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
                View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
                Snackbar.make(v1,"Nombre de la ciclovía: "+marker.getTitle()+ System.getProperty ("line.separator")+"Caracteristicas de la vía: "+marker.getSnippet(),Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

aqui esta el layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.ciclomapp.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: zhet te refieres a que esta muy abajo? te sugiero agregues tu layout.

Comment: si, eso mismo, esta muy abajo, lo agrego enseguida

Comment: @Elenasys listo, lo agregue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En lugar de obtener la vista "root" mediante:

```
View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
```

obten la del contenedor que en tu caso es un `RelativeLayout` con id `content_main`:

```
  View v1 = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.content_main);
  Snackbar.make(v1,"Nombre de la ciclovía: !!!!!!!!",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

Comment: sigue igual, después de cambiarlo se mantuvo en la misma posicion

Comment: olvidalo es por que se agrega a la vista del root, he actualizado! =0

Comment: quedo perfecta, una vez mas salvándome el pellejo jajaja

Comment: Haha me gusta esa frase, saludos Zhet!